# The reference constraint is being triggered but unable to select rows from the table that would trigger it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to update a bunch of different tables in my database.
However, when the update is completed, I am unable to delete a record from another table due to a foreign key constraint. However, other databases on different servers will accept the change just fine. And upon creating a fresh new db and applying a series of update scripts against it to pre-populate the data, it fails as well.

It should be SQL Server 2016.

I have had a coworker attempt to rebuild indexes and update usages and it still failed.

```
--- Query 1
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c.[name], t.[name]),
        SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) AS SchemaName,
        c.[name] AS ColName, 
        t.[name] AS TableName
FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE   c.[name] IN (...)
AND     t.[name] NOT IN (...)
ORDER BY ColName, TableName
```

I select out a collection of schema, columns and tables that meet my criteria and generate dynamic SQL for each combination.

```
--- Query 2
SET @sql = 'UPDATE ' + @schemaName + '.' + @tableName + ' SET ' + @colName + ' = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @p1) + ' WHERE ' + @colName + ' = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @p2)
```

Most/all of the tables returned by query 1 have a FK constraint against another table.
And query 2 seems to execute correctly without issue.

Table definition is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [Table1](
    [Table1ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ColX] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ColY] [int] NOT NULL,
    ...
    [ColZ] [int] NOT NULL,
    ...
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [Table1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_Table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Table1ID] ASC,
    [ColY] ASC,
    [ColZ] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [Table1]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Table1_ColY_Table2_ColY] FOREIGN KEY([ColY])
REFERENCES [Table2] ([ColY])

CREATE TABLE [Table2](
    [Table2ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ColY] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ColZ] [int] NOT NULL,
    ...
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [Table2] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_Table2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Table2ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [Table2] ADD  CONSTRAINT [UK_Table2_ColY] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ColY] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

My expectation is that when I run the following:

```
DELETE  FROM Table2
WHERE   ColY = @p2
```

that I do not trigger FK_Table1_ColY_Table2_ColY.

Especially because:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     Table1
WHERE    ColY = @p2
```

returns no records.

The complete error message is as follows:

```
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint 
"FK_Table1_ColY_Table2_ColY". The conflict occurred in database "localhost", table 
"dbo.Table1", column 'ColY'.
```

Comment: Can you post the complete error message? If Table1 doesn't have any @p2 the delete should not trigger the constrain violation.

Comment: Do you have triggers on any of the tables? Are you running this within a transaction?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Updated with the full error message.

Comment: @Alex No, there are no triggers on either of the two tables. 
I believe it is being run in a transaction as a part of our update process and I have wrapped the query in a BEGIN TRAN/ROLLBACK so as to not corrupt the data.

Comment: This should not generally be possible, and I can't reproduce it with the definitions as given on a trivial database. Try putting both the `SELECT *` and `DELETE` in one single transaction with a `WITH (TABLOCKX)` hint on both tables, to ensure you cannot possibly be dealing with stale or concurrently updated data. If this still shows no rows present and the statements nevertheless failing, the only possible explanations should be index/data corruption or an engine bug. Try `DBCC CHECKDB` and `ALTER TABLE [Table] REBUILD`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert What am I looking for with DBCC CHECKDB? What things should jump out to me as issues, I've personally never used this command before. I receive a message ```CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors in database 'localhost'.```

Comment: Easy -- if `DBCC CHECKDB` reports any errors, you've got a problem. If it doesn't, you don't. (Well, none that `CHECKDB` spotted, it isn't *completely* airtight.) If you want it even easier, `DBCC CHECKDB WITH NO_INFOMSGS` will keep completely quiet if there are no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there was an issue fixed in an update to sql server.

[Support Microsoft: Fix referential integrity constraints not being evaluated correctly.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/4503379/fix-referential-integrity-constraints-are-not-evaluated-correctly-when)

The work around fixes detailed are:

1. Use a compatibility level below 130.
2. Modify the referencing table to change the index structure.

Comment: I hit a similar bug in SQL 2019, also fixed with an update - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/314945/the-delete-statement-conflicted-with-the-reference-constraint-but-theres-no